# How to HSM device store and protect private key?

Tags: security, private-key, pci-compliance, hsm

I am studing about HSM device  but i dont know this device protects and saves the Key?
HSM saves key outside or inside? If inside, How many key the HSM can protect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That all depends on the HSM in question.  Different vendors do things differently.

There are some which store the keys in encrypted files (Thales springs to mind), while others store them internally (Gemalto springs to mind here).

The number of keys that can be stored is often dictated by which option boxes you tick when you order the device.  The more you pay, the more it will store.

Comment: Utimaco gives you the option of storing them internally or externally (at the application level, ie it isn't something "you buy up front", and you can have one app storing its keys internally, and others with keys stored externally (AES256 encrypted) using the same device/device cluster.  And the number you can store is dictated by the physical media (or logical file system max file size) you use, and the kind of keys you are storing, and the metadata associated with the key -- "it depends"